# HTTP Keep-Alive can sustain long polling?

Tags: java, http, jakarta-ee, tcp, timeout

My understanding of long polling is, sending a request to server, and server taking some time to return data to us, or gradually send back the data.

I encounter a problem with my java servlet app (run in weblogic server), after client fire a request, the processing time of the backend servlet took about 1 minute, when the servlet trying to send back the response, I encounter "broken pipe" problem.

This problem is reported by my client, I can't reproduce it in my environment, in fact, I written a small servlet to test when I will eventually encounter the read-timeout issue. Un-surprisingly, my browser can be waiting server to return response for more than 5 minutes.

What could be the reasons that my client encouter such broken pipe issue?

How possibly can I solve it?

According to http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/813827,

> Internet Explorer reuses the same TCP/IP socket that was used to
>   receive the initial request until the socket is idle for one minute.
>   After the connection is idle for one minute, Internet Explorer resets
>   the connection. A new TCP/IP socket is used to receive additional
>   requests.

Is that possible the keep-alive timeout (1 minutes) actually overwrite the 'read-timeout' (my understand 'read-timeout' has very damn long timing), so it cause the TCP connection close?

So now, this also come back with a question, when it says "idle for one minute", what is the definition of "idle"? now TCP open a socket and send out the request, while waiting server to process large data and return, does it mean it is "idle" now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that possible the keep-alive timeout (1 minutes) actually overwrite the 'read-timeout' (my understand 'read-timeout' has very damn long timing), so it cause the TCP connection close?

No, neither the HTTP keep-alive nor the TCP keep-alive (it is unclear which one you actually mean and they have different meanings) have anything to do with timeouts because the socket is idle.

> what is the definition of "idle"?

Idle means no data get transferred.

Comment: Not really. HTTP keep-alive means that the server doesn't close the connection, the client does, at its discretion, subject to these idle timeouts, where  'idle' means 'not in use', and wouldn't/shouldn't include any time spent waiting for a response.

Comment: @EJP, so meaning, can I say, while HTTP socket waiting the response to come back (it already fired the request to server), in client side, the socket is not considered as 'idle' even there are no data being transferred at the moment (waiting response to come back)?

Comment: HTTP keep-alive only handles the case after both request and response are done. In this case (that is no request in process) both client and server can close the underlying TCP connection at any time. And because HTTP keep-alive does not apply when the client waits for a response it does not help to change it to make this problem go away.

Comment: The usual way to handle situations where the server takes a long time to prepare the final response is to use redirects or http refresh to borrow more time. With each redirect you get a new request and thus the idle timeout starts again.